# Missing taints on control-plane

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am starting up a cluster using minikube and found the node to be started as control-plane node, but interestingly I found the taints to be none. Because the taints is none, I see pods being scheduled on this node.

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
minikube       Ready    control-plane   76d   v1.24.3
minikube-m02   Ready    <none>          18m   v1.24.3
```

And below is the taint information,

```
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=
                    node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 21 Aug 2022 22:27:29 -0500
Taints:             <none>
```

Any idea why there is this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of minikube because tainting the control plane node is not a Kubernetes requirement especially for the dev/test environments.

You may manually taint your master node using:

```
kubectl taint nodes minikube node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

After you apply the taint, drain the master node so the pods scheduled on it shift to the worker node.

```
kubectl drain minikube --ignore-daemonsets
```